# Why is this regular expression matching giving this result?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

With the metacharacter `+` the pattern must at least appear one time. While trying to match `a[ab]+` in this string: `abbaaabbbbaaaaa` using python's `re.findall()`, I expected it to return all this possible matches starting from the first letter `a` as in `['ab', 'abb', 'abba', 'abbaaa', ... etc]` until reaching the whole string (which is also a match). Furthermore, I think it also applies to every single `a` in the string not only the first one, so I suppose the matched results will be more than this.

This the code I used:

```
import re

string = 'abbaaabbbbaaaaa'
matches = re.findall('a[ab]+', string)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

However, the result is only `abbaaabbbbaaaaa` (the whole string). So What is it that I understand wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[ab]+` will match a single string (assuming it matches at all). The entire string `abbaaabbbbaaaaa` matches that regex, so you get one match: the entire string. It does not give you every little piece that might match.

Put differently, each match of `a` and `[ab]` "consumes" a character. That is, the matching character is "used up," and the program moves to the next character. In general, that's what you want: you want to see if the whole string matches, or how much of it matches, as opposed to finding all the bits and pieces that make up a bigger match.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions only find non-overlapping matches (unless you're using special tricks like [positive lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

Furthermore, your `+` [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) is greedy by default, matching as many characters as possible. If you add a `?` to it, it becomes lazy, so it stops at the first possible point. That gives you a list of non-overlapping matches, which however are not what you're expecting either:

```
['ab', 'aa', 'ab', 'aa', 'aa']
# as in ABbAAABbbbAAAAa
```

If you do

```
matches = re.findall('(?=(a[ab]+))', string)
```

you get all the matches from each possible starting point in the string:

```
['abbaaabbbbaaaaa',
 'aaabbbbaaaaa',
 'aabbbbaaaaa',
 'abbbbaaaaa',
 'aaaaa',
 'aaaa',
 'aaa',
 'aa']
```

By applying the regex recursively to all these submatches, you will then get all the possible matches (which are quite numerous).

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are a character class, meaning *match any one of these characters*.

Therefore, `[ab]+` matches one or more characters that are either a or b in a row.  Your pattern will gobble up the whole string with a single match.

What you might want is:

```
re.findall('a(?:ab)+', string)
```

Note that `(?:`...`)` is a non-capturing group.  It works the same as `(`...`)` would in this pattern, but it is more efficient, since it doesn't save the subgroups (which you don't need).